# How do I use one row to pull multiple other rows from the same mySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So, lets say i have a user table. Each user has the ability to be in a team with upto 3 other users. So for now i have a column for each spot in the team(4 columns total, so your own id fills in a spot so you know where you fit in the team). And i put the ids to the other members of the team in each of the other columns. In the end, everyone on one team would have the same values in those 4 columns.

How would i query sql to look at those ids and pull the info for all the other users on there team (so by looking at one user, i can pull all 4 team members rows)? Is this the most efficient way of storing that data?

Comment: Normalize your data and have a team_members table instead of duplicating the team details against each user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Normalize your data from the beginning.** It will pay off big time in a long run. This way you'll be able to normally maintain and query your data.

A proposed schema in a simplified form may look like this

```sql
CREATE TABLE users
(
  `user_id` int not null auto_increment primary key, 
  `user_name` varchar(5)
);  
CREATE TABLE teams
(
  `team_id` int not null auto_increment primary key, 
  `team_name` varchar(5)
);
CREATE TABLE team_users
(
  `team_id` int, 
  `user_id` int,
  primary key (team_id, user_id),
  foreign key (team_id) references teams (team_id),
  foreign key (user_id) references users (user_id)
);
```

If you need to pull all members for a team with a name 'team2'

```sql
SELECT t.team_id, t.team_name, u.user_id, u.user_name
  FROM team_users tu JOIN teams t
    ON tu.team_id = t.team_id JOIN users u
    ON tu.user_id = u.user_id
 WHERE t.team_name = 'team2'
```

If you need to get all members of a team where user with `user_id = 2` is a member

```sql
SELECT t.team_id, t.team_name, u.user_id, u.user_name
  FROM team_users tu JOIN team_users tu2
    ON tu.team_id = tu2.team_id JOIN teams t
    ON tu.team_id = t.team_id JOIN users u
    ON tu.user_id = u.user_id 
 WHERE tu2.user_id = 2
```

Sample output:

```
| TEAM_ID | TEAM_NAME | USER_ID | USER_NAME |
|---------|-----------|---------|-----------|
|       2 |     team2 |       2 |     user2 |
|       2 |     team2 |       4 |     user4 |
|       2 |     team2 |       5 |     user5 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/adae6/7)** demo

Comment: Thanks, I'm fairly new to SQL and databases so this will take me some time to wrap my head around how to use it, but you've given me what I needed!

Comment: As I study this, I'm getting hung up here: This query only works if I know the team. But I know the user first, not the team. So, having a users id first, how do I pull the rows for all his other teammate?

Comment: @DauntlessRob You're quite welcome :) That is what `JOIN`s are for. See updated answer and sqlfiddle example.

Answer (score 0):

I think first of all you should not care about this being the most efficient way of storing such data, but the most logical. MySQL is generally pretty good at being a relational database, so the following should perform extremely well:

Make two tables. One for users (with IDs), one for the teams.

In the team table, you put the 4 IDs of the users. You can put in a team ID and name or whatever if you like, but don't have to.

Then you find the team entry like this:

```
SELECT * FROM team WHERE u1 == ? OR u2 == ? OR u3 == ? or u4 == ?;
```

And then you query for the users separately.

To improve performance, you may then think about table joins, joining the user's data onto the team entry:

```
SELECT * from team 
    LEFT JOIN user user1 ON u1 == user1.id
    LEFT JOIN user user2 ON u2 == user2.id
    LEFT JOIN user user3 ON u3 == user3.id
    LEFT JOIN user user4 ON u4 == user4.id;
```

This will fetch you one row per team with all user details in it.

### Even better: many to many

A many to many relationship has two tables (users and teams) and a relation table (team_users), that contains pairs of IDs and potential other values (e.g. position on the team).

Then you can map the user to his team, and get all the users (and additional values) from that, all using only the relation table. Using joins, you can again fetch your information along with the mapping, reducing the number of queries. MySQL is really good at this!